# Convert a pandas pivot table to 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I had a 2D data like this:

```
    "X"   "Y"   "Intensity"
   1000    10      75
   1000    20      65
   2000    30      80
   2000    20      60
   2000    40      55
   3000    10      65
   3000    20      45
   4000    30      80
```

Using the code:

> df.pivot(index='X', columns='Y', values='Intensity')

I converted it to a pandas table like this:

```
    "Y" 10  20  30  40 
"X"
1000    75  65  NaN NaN
2000    NaN 60  80  55
3000    65  45  NaN NaN 
4000    NaN NaN 80  NaN
```

Using the code:

> np.interpolate()

And then interpolated it to fill some of the values like this:

```
    "Y" 10  20  30  40 
"X"
1000    75  65  NaN NaN
2000    55  60  80  55
3000    65  45  60 NaN 
4000    NaN 60  80  NaN
```

Now I want it to be converted back to the initial 2D data format in order to plot a contour map.

I hope this is sufficient information to answer my query. Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df.stack().reset_index()
```